# Unity camera not properly turning

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

Im working on my first project in unity and I am running into a problem where the camera is not turning properly, i cannot look up or down only left and right and even then it does not turn the camera but the angle of the environment here are some screenshots of the setup of the project.[[image]
[image]

Comment: does the demo scene work? the one which comes with the UnityPackage?

Comment: You could try to un-tick Freeze Rotation for X and Z in your GVRMain rigidbody properties. I say this but i have no clue about what is this GVRMain, but if your camera is child of it, this could explains your problem